# Add existing Kotlin project to my existing Java project

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Sorry for a probably stupid question.

I need to add an existing open-source `Kotlin` project ([Lightning-Browser](https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser)) to an existing `Java` project I'm working on currently.

I've tried different ways, but no matter what I did, I was always getting different build errors.

I've tried many times to google and fix error, but this was leading to another error. I've spent 2 working days and got no result at all.

For now, I'm trying to achieve this on an empty Java project created by `Android Studio`.

This is the steps of what I did:

1. Create an Empty Activity Java project using Android Studio.
2. Add some Kotlin class to it, so Android Studio adds Kotlin support for you.
3. Fix build errors (Use RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS in settings.gradle).
4. Copy `app` folder of `Lightning-Browser` project to `myproject/lb-app` folder.
5. Add `include ':lb-app'` line to `settings.gradle`.

Trying to build: getting `Plugin with id 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount' not found.` error.

Am I on a right way to do my task? Is `include ':lb-app'` line OK?

Here is the full code I'm currently working on: https://anonfiles.com/73wfIfr2yc/UseLB_zip.

Comment: "Is include ':lb-app' line OK?" -- no, because Lightning Browser is an app, not a library. You will not be able to use it as a library without modifications.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please guide me with what modifications do I need? Any article/tutorial maybe?

Comment: "Could you please guide me with what modifications do I need?" -- no, because I do not know what you are actually trying to accomplish and I do not know the implementation of Lightning Browser. At a high level, you should fork the Lightning Browser project and split it into an app and a library, where the library contains the pieces that you need in your own app. Then, use that library in your project. But I cannot tell you what those pieces are, nor how to separate them cleanly within the Lightning Browser code base.